# CSS text to display on a single row

Tags: css

I have the following piece of CSS code

```
<div class="ws-contact-info">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Phone:</h2>
<p style="text-align: center;"><a href="#">(077) 4223 0866</a></p>
</div>
</div>

h2, p {display: inline-block;}
```

The formatting and sizing of text is exactly how I want but it is displayed in a column on my the top of my homepage.

```
Phone:
(077) 4223 0866
```

I would like it to display as follows

```
Phone:(077) 4223 0866
```

Could anyone kindly help?

Comment: `display: inline` or write on single line

Comment: Learn the semantic meanings of elements and use them correctly. "Phone" shouldn't be in a header, but rather in a `span`.

Comment: `h2` and `p` are block elements by default. You need to make them inline, or inline-block, or use flexbox or something. Btw., these are _basics_ of layouting with CSS, IMHO - you should be learning those from a couple of beginner’s tutorials, rather than asking about this here.

Comment: `h2` and `p` are both block level so they are 100% wide. Make them both `display:inline-block` would be one method. or just make the parent `display:flex`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned here, `h2` and `p` tags are `block` elements, meaning they're displayed beneath each other because they take 100% of the width, if you want them to show besides each other, you can use `display: inline-block` or `display: flex` (there are a few more options for that). You can also write them on the same line and/or use `span`s to differentiate them with styling.

```
h2, p { display: inline-block }
```

or

```
<h1 style="display: inline-block">Hi</h1>
```

Comment: @Owen, glad to help you! Please consider marking this as accepted if it solved your problem and answered your question.

Comment: Can i put this display: inline-block in the header and paragrpah tags? <h2 display: inline-block style="text-align: center;">Phone1:</h2> this doesn't work for me.

Comment: There is no `display` property in HTML. You need to put it in your styling

Comment: would suggest you to make a seperat css class for that `.inline{ display: inline-block; }` and add `class="inline"` to your h1 and your p tags. So you can resuse the class for other elements and it is easier to mantain and read

Comment: I have tried to declare my  CSS for h2 and p by adding h2, p {display: inline-block;} below my bottom </div> tag in the html. All it does is on the browser is print the text  h2, p {display: inline-block;}. Am i not declaring the css for h2 and p correctly?

Comment: You need to put it inside a `<style>` tag. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style

Comment: thank you so much for your patience Roy!!. working now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **inline-block** like that to show them in the same line and you can change the **margin** to center it again.

```
<div class="ws-contact-info">
 <div class="col-sm-4">
   <h2 style="text-align: center; display: inline-block; margin-left: 40%;">Phone:</h2>
   <p style="text-align: center; display: inline-block; margin: auto;">
    <a href="#">(077) 4223 0866</a>
   </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also i suggest you to check display types for further information about how to display like the way you want them.

Answer (score 0):

Both h2 and P tags are block element. If you need to show the content in same line you need to add below css

```
h2,p{
  display:inline-block;/*or use display: flex  or display:inline
}
```

Else, you may change the HTML(without css) tag like below

```
<div class="ws-contact-info">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Phone:<span><a href="tel:00742230866">(077) 4223 0866</a><span></h2>
</div>
</div>
```